# Objectbox delete Entity and remove ToOne<> link to it in another Entity. App now only works on first build variant when the change was made

Tags: android, objectbox

In my app I have the two Entities `CardEntity` and `DeckCard`. I want to remove `CardEntity` completely, and update `DeckCard` to no longer reference it.

```
public class CardEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private char letter;
    private int bonus;

    public CardEntity() {
    }

    public CardEntity(char letter) {
        this(letter, 0);
    }

    public CardEntity(char letter, int bonus) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    public int getBonus() {
        return bonus;
    }

    public void setLetter(char letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public void setBonus(int bonus) {
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }
}
```

and

```
@io.objectbox.annotation.Entity
public class DeckCard extends BaseEntity {

    private Integer position;
    private ToOne<CardEntity> card;

    public DeckCard() {
    }

    public DeckCard(Integer position, ToOne<CardEntity> card) {
        this.position = position;
        this.card = card;
    }

    public Integer getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Integer position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public ToOne<CardEntity> getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    public void setCard(ToOne<CardEntity> card) {
        this.card = card;
    }
}
```

I want to remove `CardEntity` entirely and replace `DeckCard` with

```
public class DeckCard extends BaseEntity {

    private Integer position;
    private char letter;
    private int bonus;

    public DeckCard() {
    }

    public DeckCard(Integer position, char letter, int bonus) {
        this.position = position;
        this.letter = letter;
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public Integer getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Integer position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    public void setLetter(char letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public int getBonus() {
        return bonus;
    }

    public void setBonus(int bonus) {
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }
}
```

This works fine, as expected. However, it only works on whatever **Build Variant** I had selected at the time in Android Studio. By selected I mean the next time the app runs and the `objectbox-models/default.json` file is updated.

If I am on *debug* build variant then it won't work on *release* build variant, and vice versa.

I am pretty certain that I only have to use the `Uid` command when I'm renaming something or changing it's type. In this instance I am doing neither, I am deleting and creating something new.

Below is an included git diff to the change created by objectbox to the default.json` file.

```
index 93401bf..85ef145 100644
--- a/core/objectbox-models/default.json
+++ b/core/objectbox-models/default.json
@@ -56,28 +56,8 @@
       "relations": []
     },
     {
-      "id": "3:6780553593369094070",
-      "lastPropertyId": "3:5487168684448628175",
-      "name": "CardEntity",
-      "properties": [
-        {
-          "id": "1:6704627251462640845",
-          "name": "id"
-        },
-        {
-          "id": "2:3991826258957414994",
-          "name": "letter"
-        },
-        {
-          "id": "3:5487168684448628175",
-          "name": "bonus"
-        }
-      ],
-      "relations": []
-    },
-    {
       "id": "5:5013495804474067017",
-      "lastPropertyId": "3:4210233198992719300",
+      "lastPropertyId": "5:3189718515123354120",
       "name": "DeckCard",
       "properties": [
         {
@@ -89,16 +69,19 @@
           "name": "position"
         },
         {
-          "id": "3:4210233198992719300",
-          "indexId": "1:4945633363495390935",
-          "name": "cardId"
+          "id": "4:256499331611759584",
+          "name": "letter"
+        },
+        {
+          "id": "5:3189718515123354120",
+          "name": "bonus"
         }
       ],
       "relations": []
     },
     {
       "id": "6:5212062744213571670",
-      "lastPropertyId": "2:2822761128112662405",
+      "lastPropertyId": "3:3928832151786754926",
       "name": "DeckEntity",
       "properties": [
         {
@@ -107,8 +90,11 @@
         },
         {
           "id": "2:2822761128112662405",
-          "indexId": "3:1461174128207782541",
-          "name": "date"
+          "name": "value"
+        },
+        {
+          "id": "3:3928832151786754926",
+          "name": "deckType"
         }
       ],
       "relations": [
@@ -362,10 +348,13 @@
   "retiredEntityUids": [
     4969708316960283445,
     5055976600245924974,
-    4563426853935656920
+    4563426853935656920,
+    6780553593369094070
   ],
   "retiredIndexUids": [
-    1897667010269871647
+    1897667010269871647,
+    1461174128207782541,
+    4945633363495390935
   ],
   "retiredPropertyUids": [
     5471484579006047884,
@@ -378,7 +367,11 @@
     6425939462895623468,
     6798215028749536251,
     3730774925178609899,
-    808949111095751851
+    808949111095751851,
+    4210233198992719300,
+    6704627251462640845,
+    3991826258957414994,
+    5487168684448628175
   ],
   "retiredRelationUids": [
     785742710602534748,
```

UPDATED: to add some more clarity to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** the observed behavior could not reproduced with the current version of ObjectBox (e.g. 2.5.1), but with an old version (2.0.0).

Summary:

- You intend to "merge" the properties of two entity types into one
- CardEntity is dropped
- DeckCard gets two additional properties and drops the ToOne to CardEntity

Comment: No not merge two into one, sorry. Completely get rid of CardEntity and instead of having that in the DeckCard, i just want to use the two primitives instead. Nothing diff in the entity classes between builds either. As for the 'not work' I'll grab a stack trace and post it in another comment

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tYDUv1yk - it starts at what I think is the beginning of the crash, and I don't know where the crash *actually* ends so there's probably a lot of waffle after

Comment: Behaviour of 'not work' is the app compiles, installs, starts and then within less than 1s crashes. There is zero java errors in any error logs that really mention the app package name, and the pastebin above is based on trawling through the whole phone logs, but at least it mentions the package.

Comment: "Completely get rid of CardEntity and instead of having that in the DeckCard, i just want to use the two primitives instead." -> Yes. I think we are referring to the same thing. "Merging" the properties of two entities... I'll clarify... For the native crash, I just created https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/827 - definitely looks like a bug...

Comment: Ah damn, a bug in the underlying library! That doesn't sound like something that's going to get fixed all that soon! Thinking about it, the fact it only happens in one build variant, makes me think there's something in the gradle build task that is doing this, when it removes the CardEntity. I've tried uninstalling both apps, so in theory there's no residue of previous objectbox stuff on the app, but I think we both know that's not always the case with android.

Comment: UM, I'm embarassed to say that I wasn't on the latest build (I was still on 2.0.0) and I've just updated and I *think* that it's working!! I'm using the latest build on my server, so had it in my head I'd updates the app too! If it crashes again I'll get back to you, but I'll give you the all clear in the next day or so, and I'll accept your answer too, I'll also comment on the github ticket you opened. Appreciate your hard work, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update! Hope it works out; let's see what happens...

Comment: Confirming all fixed with a library update. Thanks @Markus